# HTML5 - Efficiently Plot Huge 2D Heatmaps

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, plot, heatmap

I would like to QUICKLY generate a 2D heatmap with ~3 million points. My current attempt, using vanilla javascript to write to the `<canvas>` with a single thread, is too slow (~1-2 seconds).  How can this be done easily, efficiently?

I'm open to using an existing library like THREE.js or pixi.js if it can do this quickly.

**Details**

So the steps are:

1. Find the min/max value in the list
2. For each point: map to a color (based on min/max above) and determine x/y location (just increment for each point)
3. Write to the page e.g. a `<canvas>` element

**My slowish solution**
In [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/th8qLxjr/) and below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="1500px" height="1500px" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;" ></canvas>

<script>
function getInterpolatedColor(colorscale, min, max, val) {
  var maxIndex = colorscale.length - 1,
      colorIncrement = (max - min) / maxIndex;

  if (colorIncrement === 0) {
    return 255;
  }

  var baseColor = Math.floor((val - min) / colorIncrement),
      percentage = (val - (min + colorIncrement * baseColor)) / colorIncrement;
  if (percentage > 1.0) {
    percentage = 0.0;
    baseColor = baseColor + 1;
  }

  var color = 255;
  if ((baseColor >= 0) && (baseColor < (maxIndex))) {
    color = colorscale[baseColor] +
            ((colorscale[baseColor + 1] - colorscale[baseColor]) * percentage);
  } else {
    color = (baseColor < 0) ? colorscale[0] : colorscale[maxIndex];
  }

  return color;
}


var canv = document.getElementById('myCanvas'),
    xSize = 1500,
    ySize = 1500,
    count = xSize * ySize,
    values = new Array(count),
    min = 101,
    max = -1;

for (var i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
  var val = Math.random() * 100;
  values[i] = val;
  if(val>max) max = val;
  if(val<min) min = val;
}

// #FF0000 #FF8000 #FFFF00 #00FF00 #0000FF #4C007F
var rgbScale = {
  "red" : [255, 255, 255, 0, 0, 76],
  "green" : [0, 128, 255, 255, 0, 0],
  "blue" : [0, 0, 0, 0, 255, 127]
};

var ctx = canv.getContext("2d"),
    id = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, xSize, ySize),
    data = id.data;
for (var xIndex = 0; xIndex < xSize; ++xIndex) {
  for (var yIndex = 0; yIndex < ySize; ++yIndex) {
    var index = ((xIndex * ySize) + yIndex),
        canvasId = index*4,
        val = values[index] * 1;

    var red = Math.floor(getInterpolatedColor(rgbScale["red"], min, max, val));
    red = (red > 255) ? 255 : red;

    var green = Math.floor(getInterpolatedColor(rgbScale["green"], min, max, val));
    green = (green > 255) ? 255 : green;

    var blue = Math.floor(getInterpolatedColor(rgbScale["blue"], min, max, val));
    blue = (blue > 255) ? 255 : blue;

    data[canvasId + 0] = red;
    data[canvasId + 1] = green;
    data[canvasId + 2] = blue;
    data[canvasId + 3] = 255;
  }
}

ctx.putImageData(id, 0, 0);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: will the values always be positive? you're getting directly into micro optimization, there's no glaring inefficiency shown...

Comment: The algorithm shouldn't care if the values are positive/negative - they will map to the colorscale accordingly.

Comment: ok, well i was going to say that there's faster ways to get an int than Math.floor of your input is positive. you really are looking at micro optimizations like that in order to get any more speed...

Comment: OK - I was wondering if multi-threading would help (or perhaps the GPU, although I bet I/O would kill runtime).

Comment: if it's slow enough, additional threads can help. there are teardown and shipping costs with those, but it might be worth it. since you only do single-pixel transforms (not neighboring ones like blur) you can simply chop your array into 4 pieces, compute them separately, slap em together, and draw the data